# Weird / different value for CSS background property

Tags: html, css, svg

I was inspecting the code of a website and I noticed they had an unusual value for the background property of an element via CSS. It seems to be a gradient. Does anyone know what it is? If it is valid? And what browsers support it?

Here is the code:

```
background:transparent url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEwMCAxMDAiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iaGF0MCIgZ3JhZGllbnRVbml0cz0ib2JqZWN0Qm91bmRpbmdCb3giIHgxPSI1MCUiIHkxPSIxMDAlIiB4Mj0iNTAlIiB5Mj0iLTEuNDIxMDg1NDcxNTIwMmUtMTQlIj4KPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjY1Ii8+CjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjkiLz4KICAgPC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD4KCjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2hhdDApIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
```

I appreciate any and all help!

Thanks in Advance! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first thing is to [**de-base64**](http://www.google.com/search?q=decode+base64) it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <linearGradient id="hat0" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="50%" y1="100%" x2="50%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.65" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.9" />
    </linearGradient>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#hat0)" />
</svg>
```

Thus you can see that yes, it is a gradient. Non-IE browsers support this, and IE 9+ supports it as well.

Comment: oh okay, so it is the same thing as a .svg file as the background? And has the same support?

Are there any advantages of using the base-64 version over not doing do / using the .svg file version ?

Comment: Using the base64 version means one less network access. Now of course, base64 versions are going to be 33% larger (3 characters take 4 base64 "digits" to encode) but that doesn't matter much on something this small. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri for Data URI support; IE 8+ allows it in linked CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

It is base64 encoded SVG file.  This convention is a means of using a SVG graphic file as an embedded background image.  I do the same thing with the Travelocity logo here http://mailmarkup.org/slideshow.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

I think all modern browsers support it. This is a scalable vector graphic (you often find those used for maps on wikipedia) file that is base64-encoded, that means it consists many bytes which wer converted to be used in ASCII character sets.